# Creating query in VBA to get data from table with a name that is a SQL-keyword

Tags: sql, vba, keyword

I'm trying to get data from a database in VBA. The problem is that someone has named the table ORDER. Because I'm working in VBA I can't use "" around ORDER. I've tried single quotes ('') en [], but nothing seems to work. Does anybody know a way to work around this problem? I can't change the name of the table, because the database is also used in an other application.

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

In VBA you could escape **"** by **""**. Here is a little test:

```
debug.Print "Test""Test2"
```

That prints

```
Test"Test2
```

Now you could build with this your statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which is your Database server.
You can use a simple workaround, if nothing else works.
If a table with ORDER name is accepted by you RDBMS, then create a view (or a new query, if Access) like the following:

```
CREATE VIEW MY_NEW_NAME
AS SELECT * FROM ORDER;
```

and then SELECT from the new view...